# Why do I need to take a reference when slicing a slice?

Tags: rust

The following code compiles:

```
fn main() {
    let slices:&[i32] = &[1,2,3];
    let subSlice = &slices[1..3];
    print!("{:?}\n",subSlice);
}
```

but this fails:

```
fn main() {
    let slices:&[i32] = &[1,2,3];
    let subSlice = slices[1..3];
    print!("{:?}\n",subSlice);
}
```

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[i32]` cannot be known at compilation time
--> src/main.rs:3:9
 |
3 |     let subSlice = slices[1..3];
  |         ^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

`slices` is already a slice/reference (`&[i32]`) created with `&`. Why do I have to use `&` again in `&slices[1..3]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a language standpoint, index access into a slice is implemented in terms of the `Index<Idx>` trait.

This trait is defined as:

```
pub trait Index<Idx> where
    Idx: ?Sized,{
    type Output: ?Sized;

    // Required method
    fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output;
}
```

Now it looks like using this should return a reference to the indexed element.
In fact, if we call this directly:

```
use std::ops::Index;

fn main() {
    let slices:&[i32] = &[1,2,3];
    //let subSlice = slices[1..3];
    let sub_slice: &[i32] = slices.index(1..3);
    print!("{:?}\n", sub_slice);
}
```

The returned type is indeed `&[i32]`. ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bf180803ae47241cd4fe969153fab41b))

However, the [Index documentation page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) tells us the following:

> container[index] is actually syntactic sugar for *container.index(index)

which means that in your case, the returned slice gets automatically dereferenced into a `[i32]`, which is unsized. Therefore, you need to borrow it manually to obtain a `&[i32]`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is when you index `slices` variable, it returns `[i32]` which is not fixed length.

As you can see in this [trait implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-Index%3CI%3E-for-%5BT%5D), it returns `[T]` instead of `&[T]`

So the compiler does not know how much memory to allocate. The compiler tells you, "hey I do not know the length, but what I know is the size of a pointer" (an inmmutable reference).

So the compiler suggest you to borrow `[i32]` so the final type is `&[i32]`. That is a pointer which is fixed length therefore the compiler can allocate the memory into the stack.

Comment: As @SirDarius explains, looking at the `Index` trait is misleading because `index()` appears to return a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The slice in general has the type [T] with no indication of the size. for instance an [i32] has no size information attached to it (like how many number of elements this will have in contrast to arrays which has the form [i32; 3] where 3 indicates the size). The rust needs the size information at the compile time. So this means that a slice has always to be behind a reference (since a reference has fixed size, that is it a pointer to some memory).